# Shopware 6 custom entity fields are not updated via admin api

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

i have a custom entity defined in entities.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/System/CustomEntity/Xml/entity-1.0.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_entity_search">
        <fields>
            <string name="media_hash" store-api-aware="true" />
            <json name="data" store-api-aware="true" />
        </fields>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

when i use the admin api to insert a new custom entity i don't get all my fields updated.
request url:

```
http://localhost/api/custom-entity-search
```

request body:

```
{
    "name": "custom-entity-search",
    "fields": {
        "media_hash": "123hashmedia",
        "data": {"test": "1234"}
    }
}
```

The entity is created but fields "media_hash" and "data" remain null.
How can i update those fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the fields directly in the payload there is no need to specify the entity name in the payload itself, the mapping to the concrete custom entity is done over the REST-API endpoint `api/custom-entity-search`

so the request body should look like this:

```json
{
    "media_hash": "123hashmedia",
    "data": {"test": "1234"}
}
```

### Edit (to many relations)

```json
{
    "media_hash": "123hashmedia",
    "data": {"test": "1234"},
    "customer_to_many_field": [
        {
            "id": "my first customer id",
            "firstName": "The new name",
        },
        {
           ... // data for second customer if needed
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: thanks. i created the body this way because this was the example from here https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/2e4e2ca200987-create-a-new-custom-entity-resources.

Comment: if i have a many-to-many relation with the customer entity, how can i update the customer info? or how should i send the customer info so a custom_entity_search_customers is created for the new custom-entity-search ?

Comment: the documentation is for the api route to register new custom enitity types in the system, that is basically the API equivalent to the xml configuration you included here

Comment: i added an example for the to many field, hope that helps